# Why won't Paint draw this image?

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, onpaint

I am overriding the OnPaint method in my control that I've made to draw it directly from an image generated from my own `ICan3D.Graphics` class.  When I save the image (as you can see, that line is commented out) the image is correct.  When the form loads, however, it doesn't display the image as it's background.

```
Imports System

Namespace ICan3D

    Public Class RenderSurface
        Inherits Control

        Dim nImg As Graphics

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
            Dim img As Bitmap = nImg.Visual
            'img.Save("C:\image.png")
            Dim nGraphDis As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(img)
            Dim nPaintEventArgs As New PaintEventArgs(nGraphDis, New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height))
            MyBase.OnPaint(nPaintEventArgs)
        End Sub

        Private Sub RenderSurface_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
            nImg = New Graphics(Width, Height)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

I'm using VB.net so all .net answers are acceptable :)

Comment: You need to use the Graphics object of the PaintEventArgs parameter and not supply your own. See Thomas' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(nImg.Visual, 0, 0, Width, Height)
End Sub
```